Setting up Product Option Stock and Tracking with GraphQL
I need some help with the GraphQL Admin API with creating a product with options or variants that have stock.
At the moment I've set this up:
// Preparing the Data:
const prepareProducts = (products) => {
return products.map((product) => {
// Prepare color options
const colorOptions = product.variants.reduce((acc, variant) => {
  if (variant.codeColourName && !acc.includes(variant.codeColourName)) {
    acc.push(variant.codeColourName);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

const sizeOptions = product.variants.reduce((acc, variant) => {
  if (variant.codeSizeName && !acc.includes(variant.codeSizeName)) {
    acc.push(variant.codeSizeName);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

const productOptions = [];
if (colorOptions.length > 0) {
  productOptions.push({
    name: "Color",
    values: colorOptions.map((color) => ({ name: color })),
  });
}

if (sizeOptions.length > 0) {
  productOptions.push({
    name: "Size",
    values: sizeOptions.map((size) => ({ name: size })),
  });
}

return {
  title: product.productName,
  bodyHtml: product.description,
  vendor: "VENDOR",
  productType: product.categories[0]?.name || "Default Category",
  images: product.images.map((image) => ({
    src: image.urls[0]?.url || "Default Image URL",
    width: image.urls[0]?.width || 1024,
    height: image.urls[0]?.height || 1024,
  })),
  productOptions: productOptions,
  variants: product.variants.map((variant) => ({
    price: variant.price || 0,
    inventoryManagement: "SHOPIFY",
    inventoryPolicy: "DENY",
    sku: variant.fullCode,
    inventoryQuantity: variant.stock || 0,
  })),
};
});
};

Here I create the product with its media and options and stuff I need:
const createProductBatch = async (productsData) => {
  // Product creation mutation
  const productCreateMutation = `
  mutation CreateProduct($input: ProductInput!, $media: [CreateMediaInput!]) {
  productCreate(input: $input, media: $media) {
    product {
      id
      options {
        id
        name
        position
        values
        optionValues {
          id
          name
          hasVariants
        }
      }
      media(first: 10) {
        nodes {
          alt
          mediaContentType
          preview {
            status
          }
        }
      }
      metafields(first: 10) {
        edges {
          node {
            type
            namespace
            key
            value
          }
        }
      }      
    }    
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
`;

const batchSize = 5;
const delay = 500;
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
let results = [];

for (let i = 0; i < productsData.length; i += batchSize) {
const batch = productsData.slice(i, i + batchSize);
const batchResults = await Promise.all(
  batch.map(async (product) => {
    //Media
    const mediaInput = product.images.map((image) => ({
      originalSource: image.src,
      alt: image.altText || "",
      mediaContentType: "IMAGE",
    }));

    // Create the product
    const productResponse = await shopifyAPI.post(
      "",
      JSON.stringify({
        query: productCreateMutation,
        variables: {
          input: {
            title: product.title,
            bodyHtml: product.bodyHtml,
            vendor: product.vendor,
            productType: product.productType,
            metafields: [
              {
                namespace: "custom",
                key: "sync_from_api",
                type: "boolean",
                value: "true",
              },
            ],
            productOptions: product.productOptions,
          },
          media: mediaInput,
        },
      })
    );

    if (!productResponse.data || productResponse.data.errors) {
      console.error("GraphQL Error:", productResponse.data.errors);
      return null;
    }
    if (productResponse.data.data.productCreate.userErrors.length > 0) {
      console.error(
        "User Errors:",
        productResponse.data.data.productCreate.userErrors
      );
      return null;
    }

    // Product ID to use for creating variants
    const productId = productResponse.data.data.productCreate.product.id;

    return {
      productId: productId,
    };
  })
);

results = results.concat(batchResults);
await sleep(delay);
}
return results.filter((result) => result !== null);
};

Next step as far as I understand, is to use the productIDs and then activate the tracking and set the stock. How would one do that with a mutation?
